# How would you make variables in python (you'll see)

Tags: python

## Please Note That This Happened In 2019 So I picked up a few things from then

## So please don't judge me.

So I have decided to try and make a very basic language in python.

And it is pretty basic right now but I want to improve it.

And one thing all languages need: variables
And right now I have this:

```py
 # Some other if statements up here
# neon is the name of the variable
# Something programmed real quickly to show example
elif neon[0:6] == ("addvar"):
    var = neon[7:]
elif neon.startswith("add"+ var):
    invar = neon.split("add"+ var , 1)[1]
elif neon.startswith("out"+ var):
    print(invar)
```

YES it is very messy and horrid but I had to start with something and it is 
very buggy. I had to start working on math so I skipped out on the variables. I tried a few tests before e. g. Appending data to a list and whatnot.

## My Problem:

It only lets me have one variable

But now I wonder if there is a way that finally goes through the lexer and parser

## Please tell me if there is

Comment: use a dictionary whose keys are the variable names.

Comment: It would help if you showed examples of the language, and what the statements are supposed to do.

Comment: You might consider using regular expressions to parse the statements rather than slicing.

Comment: okay i am new i dont now what do really do sorry.  

Comment: yes I will try to parse instead of slicing. This is just an example I coded quickly

Comment: some of the statements in this coding language are math stuff like sum, div, Min, mul etc

Comment: As Barmar said, check out dictionaries. I think it could be helpful. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary to hold all your variables.

```
variables = {}
# some other code here
elif neon.startswith("addvar "): # addvar variablename
    var = neon.split()[1]
    variables[var] = None # create empty variable
elif neon.startswith("add "): # add variablename value
    _, var, value = neon.split()
    variables[var] = value
elif neon.startswith("out "): # out variablename
    var = neon.split()[1]
    print(variables[var])
```

Comment: Also just tested it out. How would you use the 'add'

Comment: also i am getting a ValueError for: 'To many values to unpack (expected 3)'

Comment: I fixed a lot of stuff but it still didnt work sorry :(

Comment: I've added comments showing the syntax I assumed. I did ask you to show examples of your language syntax. Since you haven't done that, I just made it up myself.

Comment: yes I know that. It is another day though and I have been working on it for a while now. I got it down to no errors but now im fixing where it prints the actual variable. it prints none instead of the variables so yeah debugging is fun. I actually saw at first your syntax but didn't understand it. I worked on it for a few hours and then I understood it. I am sorry if i didnt put any examples.

Comment: also just went thru the code it is a bit buggy. the 'splits' and '.startswith' is making it very buggy i will give you the revised code in a little bit

Comment: It's intended fr the very simple grammar that I show in the comments, and doesn't have any error checking. This isn't the real way anyone would implement a language, it's just toy code.

Comment: i know I was playing around with it and realized it would be easier if i parsed/lexed it first I just needed something to work off of you know